# Incrementally moving data across SQL Server instances without an ETL tool

Tags: sql-server

I am working on a project that involves regularly copying data from identically structured database A (on a SQL Server instance) to database B (on a different instance). I do not have the option of using SSIS or another ETL tool, so I have to use already established linked servers and write a stored procedure run as an hourly job for the incremental loads.

To copy the delta records from database A to B, I have the following stored procedure to be run as a job:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Incremental_Load
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO New_Table (New_Date_Column, Copied_Attribute)
        SELECT Datetime_Var, Attribute1
        FROM Linked_Server.Database_A.dbo.Source_Table
        WHERE Datetime_Var > (SELECT MAX(New_Date_Column) FROM New_Table);
END
```

It seems to work; only the new records, not present in the new table are inserted, based on the last record by datetime. My question has to do with performance and potential issues. If the source table gets new records every 30 minutes, and this stored procedure is run hourly, should I expect any issues, especially with regard to the subquery? Also, is it possible I will not detect all deltas? Are there any other glaring issues with this approach?

In case it matters, I do not have access to SQL Server Profiler. I also cannot create jobs, because of my privileges/roles; Someone else must do that for me. So, I would like to collect some information in advance of testing.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see any issues. As it grabs the max date value from the table which needs insertion and uses that to only query records from your linked server table, I think this will work fine.

Comment: you can use MERGE statements. should not have any performance issues and can update records from source to destination. If you do not wish to; then you also need to take into account how you want to handle records that are modified? i.e insert them as new records, update or delete depending on source. You have clause for all 3 in MERGE statements.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is SSIS not an option here? Saying that you can't use it for a purpose which it is particularly good at sounds like "I'm trying to build a house but do not have the option of using a hammer".

Comment: @BenThul Our IT department does not use SSIS, and our IT manager told me to use the existing linked servers. I would love to learn and use SSIS instead, as I also have to transform the data as it's copied over (not reflected in my post).

Comment: Have you considered transactional replication? In some situations linked servers can be a liability, i.e. when they are not managed, contain hard coded logins, insufficiently secured, used in badly performing queries.

Comment: We have a very similar process - you should consider using a `MERGE` based on the key of the table to ensure you don't have duplicates coming across. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Transactional replication won't work with views right? Unfortunately my source are views, not tables. Or, should I not be using views for something like this? Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: @Matt Is `MERGE` okay if the source is much larger than my destination, given that it performs a join on the source table? Is it possible to only join on the relevant source data? The source has data going back to 2000, whereas I want to store only the last year of data (rolling) in the destination.

Comment: In this case you replicate the underlying tables not the view